# Marginalizing multivariate-normal distribution canonical form

Tags: self-study, distributions, continuous-data, bayesian-network, multivariate-normal-distribution

Regarding the problem of margenalization of canonical forms of multivariate gaussian distribution it was mentioned in probabilistic graphical models text book that
$$\int{C(X,Y;k,h,g)}dY$$
is equivelant to
$$k' = k_{xx} - k_{xy}k^{-1}_{yy}k_{yx}$$
$$h' = h_{x} - k_{xy}k^{-1}_{yy}h_{y}$$
$$g' = g + {1\over2}(|Y|\log(2\pi) - \log|k_{yy}| + h^{T}k_{yy}h_{y})$$
given:
$$k = \begin{bmatrix}k_{xx} & k_{xy}\\k_{yx} & k_{yy}\end{bmatrix},$$
$$h = \begin{bmatrix}h_{x} \\ h_{y}\end{bmatrix},$$ 
$$g = g$$
The thing that I don't get is how these equations were derived? In the textbook it is left as an exercise (Excersies 14.6) which I am unable to solve. I have surfaced the web without any success, so your help will be much appreciated.